# Unable to insert values in a table using sequence in Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, jhipster

I want to use sequence_name.NEXTVAL to automatically compute a column's value in liquibase. The backend database is postgresql. I tried to use "valueComputed" attribute as shown in [this link](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/sequence-value-while-inserting-the-data-in-table). But it is not computing value using sequence and column's value is null at the time of insertion. How can we auto increment a column in liquibase using a sequence? Thank you for your help in advance.

My code is as below :

```
    <changeSet id="20151020000" author="jhipster">      

    <createSequence cycle="false" incrementBy="1" maxValue="1000"  minValue="50" sequenceName="seq_name" startValue="50"/>

    <createTable tableName="tablename">
                <column name="id" type="bigint" valueComputed ="seq_name.NEXTVAL">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                </column>
   </createTable>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<createTable tableName="tablename">
    <column name="id" type="bigint" defaultValueSequenceNext="seq_name">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```